# Choppy label on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a functionality where when the user clicks on a cell, the cell expands to display more labels. The height is recalculated during expansion and is based on the size of my very first label or 2nd label on the cell whichever is greater.

***Below is my code for height calculation:***

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGSize labelSize;

    if ([self.expandedCells containsObject:indexPath]) {
        // Calculate the cell height based on the address details or branch name which ever is greater.
        UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];
        BranchDetails *branchDetail = ((BranchDetails *)[self.branchDetails objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]);

        NSString *addressText = branchDetail.addressDetails;
        CGSize addressLabelSize = [addressText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(tableView.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:cellFont} context:nil].size;

        NSString *branchNameText = branchDetail.branchName;
        CGSize branchLabelSize = [branchNameText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(tableView.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:cellFont} context:nil].size;

        labelSize = (addressLabelSize.height > branchLabelSize.height) ? addressLabelSize : branchLabelSize;
    }
    else {
        NSString *cellText = [self.branchList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];

        labelSize = [cellText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(tableView.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:cellFont} context:nil].size;
    }

    CGFloat cellHeight = labelSize.height + 20;
    return [self.expandedCells containsObject:indexPath] ? cellHeight * 4 : cellHeight;
}
```

***Choppy label cell image:***
[image]

I tried adding a scroll view while creating a cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath so user can see all the details on the cell. Code for scroll view:

```
UIScrollView *scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];            
 [cell.contentView addSubview:scrollView];
```

This still adds the scroll on the table and not within the cell.

Is there a better way for me to either calculate the height, so all the labels within the cell are displayed or add a scroll inside the cell so the user can scroll within each cell after expansion to see all the details?

Comment: Instead of calculating the height, why don't you use UIAutomaticDimensions for the expanded cell? I am assuming that on clicking the cell you are inserting another cell.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this is to reiterate all UILabels in that cell and then set the height as the sum of all those views heights + gaps.

Something like this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat rowHeight = 0;

    if ([self.expandedCells containsObject:indexPath]) {

     CGFloat totalHeight = 0;

     YourCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];  

     for(UIView *v in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
       if([v isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
         UILabel *lbl = (UILabel*)v;
         totalHeight += lbl.frame.size.height; 
       }
     }
     rowHeight = totalHeight;
    }
    else {
       rowHeight = 25; // a fixed height for unexpanded rows
    }

    return rowHeight;
}
```

This will not work exactly as you want but you can get the idea how to work around it.

Comment: I had thought of this as an option, but was trying to avoid iterating over all labels for each cell as I might have large number of cells in my tableview. This is still an option, but would be the final option for me. Thanks @GeneCode! :)

Comment: You can limit to which Label you want to get the height by using tag number. For eg, you can set related labels to tag=1, and then you do if (lbl.tag==1)  totalHeight += lbl.frame.size.height;